# Python regex error, non-gredy group unexpected behaviour

Tags: python, regex

I have patterns along the lines of:

`patterns=['file.html', '../file','../file.html', 'file/', 'file']`

Id like a regular expression to match only file in these scenarios.
`rgx = re.compile(r"^ #begin line
(\.\./)? #1st group non-greedy
(.*)? #2nd group non-greedy
(\.html$)? #3rd group non-greedy
$ #pattern end", re.VERBOSE)`

The problem is with the second group.  It is not non-greedy and always gobbles up the `.html`.

Therefore, for `m= rgx.match('file.html')` output for `m.group(2)` is  `file.html`, not the desired `file`.

Am I making an obvious error, what is the problem here?

Any help is appreciated:
Thankyou

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: You don't have a non-greedy group in your regex.

Comment: Your question would be a lot clearer if you indicated included examples of inputs and desired outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah @melpomeme, thanks for the non-greedy clarification.  Moved the ? immediately after the *qualifier and not around group ().  now it works, thanks